# Linux Keyboard access through C pointers

Tags: c, linux, keyboard

I am new in C but not in programming. I want access keyboard keys through pointers. As I have tried it with far pointer and use the address 0x417 and 7th bit on with my programming in my P2 system on Windows box. Now I want to start working in Linux and trying to use the same function but nothing happen with caps lock. Any one can send me some good tutorial about the hardware and file attribute access in Ubuntu Linux.

I am very much thankful to you all.

Regards,

Comment: No such thing as a far pointer- not for the last fifteen years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't access the keyboard thru pointers on Linux.

If you are thinking of a graphical application, it uses [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X11), and its underlying protocol (which is very complex for newbies). If you are a newbie, I strongly recommend using a graphical toolkit library like [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/).

If you are thinking of a console application, I do recommend using a library like [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/s/ncurses/) or perhaps [readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

You could indeed read the raw keyboard (since e.g. the Xorg server does), but this is painful. You'll need to learn about [tty-s](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php) and the details are painful.  You'll also need to learn about the raw linux keyboard (I forgot the details, but study the Xorg server for more).

You really should explain what you want to do. Be aware that understanding in full detail what is a tty or what is the raw keyboard takes months of work. And you should be familiar with [linux](http://linux.die.net/man/2/syscalls) [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_calls) before even starting.

You should take advantage that nearly all Linux software is free; so you can study its source code.

Comment: Exactly, while interesting in its own right, if you are really after some specific application, you should probably not deal with the raw tty interface.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to read Caps Lock on Ubuntu (or any normal Linux distribution) is probably with the [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) library, [example here](http://www.libsdl.org/docs/html/guideinputkeyboard.html).

On Ubuntu you would install that library on the command line with `apt-get install libsdl-dev`.

Comment: SDL is a graphical toolkit library: it uses X11 (& OpenGL) on Linux. And I am not entirely sure that for a newbie SDL is easier to use than e.g. Gtk or Qt.

Comment: To me SDL looks way easier than Gtk and Qt.